# How can I make locate/updatedb ignore certain file extensions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, file-extension, locate

For instance, I don't want either program to find files that end in *.pyc.  I'm sure I can do this somehow using regexes or globs, but is there a way to make locate just ignore the files altogether?  It's highly doubtful that I would ever want to search for a pyc file.

Answer (score 9):

In updatedb.conf, uncomment the PRUNENAMES line and add the extension .pyc.  On my Ubuntu system by default it reads:

# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"

Change it to

PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn .pyc"

Comment: As it turns out, PRUNENAMES only works for directories, not for file names.